# .htaccess RewriteRule not working, need to generate a URL friendly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I have this dynamic link:

```
http://www.nortedigital.mx/article.php?id=36175&t=dobla_las_manos_el_snte__avala_reforma_educativa
```

and I need to convert in URL friendly like this:

```
http://www.nortedigital.mx/36174/se_enriquecio_elba_en_sexenios_del_pan.html
```

and i have this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /article.php?id=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

but doesn't work. Please, anybody can help me?

Comment: A good resource for testing RewriteRules is: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - just for future reference! (welcome to SO!)

Comment: Thank you GordonsBeard! it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must capture the query string in a RewriteCond and use that in the RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&t=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?article\.php$ /%1/%2.html? [R,L]
```

This redirects the client to request i.e. `/36174/se_enriquecio_elba_en_sexenios_del_pan.html`. Now you must server the real page. For that, we add an additional rule, similar to the one you already have in your question

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/(.+?)\.html$ /article.php?id=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

But now, there's an endless redirect loop. We break this by using an environment variable. Here is the whole complete ruleset

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SEO} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&t=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?article\.php$ /%1/%2.html? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/(.+?)\.html$ /article.php?id=$1&t=$2 [L,E=SEO:1]
```

This rule does the redirect as above, as long as the environment variable is not set. And it serves the real page from `article.php` and sets the environment variable at the same time to prevent the loop.

You can use cookies for this purpose too. But that will break, if cookies are disabled in the client.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, it works now, but produce this URL: `http://www.nortedigital.mx/36196/exito_de_reforma__solo_con_apoyo_de_maestros__epn.html?id=36196&t=exito_de_reforma__solo_con_apoyo_de_maestros__epn`I need to  delete from "?" to end, do you know how?

Comment: @lohenzoo Sorry, didn't think of that, fixed though. Just append a question mark `?` at the end of the substitution.

Comment: Thank you! it's almost allright!, but send an 404 page. I think this is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @lohenzoo If you don't have URLs like `/id/t.html`, you need an additional rule to serve the real page. Please see updated answer.