# Query string rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

i am trying to rewrite a URL for SEO purpose.

The old URL is:

```
http://www.domain.net/index.php?p=beer
```

The new URL should be:

```
http://www.domain.net/beer
```

My Code in the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Even after hours of research, i have no clue why this is not working :(

Here is the complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Teoma
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.net$ [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=uppic$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1

# Pwd service

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Service"
AuthUserFile /xxxx/www/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/.htpasswd


<Files admin.php>
Require user xxxxxxx
</Files>

Options -Indexes
```

Thanks in advance!

---

My final question to this code is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Makes working :

```
http://www.domain.net/beer
```

and beer is refering to that page:

```
http://www.domain.net/index.php?p=beer
```

Which is great! But if i put a / behind beer, e.g.:

```
http://www.domain.net/beer/
```

my beer.php file runs at another path, so no css, images, js and so on is included. Any ideas how to fix that without changing the html to http://www.domain.net/style.css ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture part of the query string, you must use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `QUERY_STRING`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /%1? [R,L]
```

This redirects the client to the new URL `http://www.domain.net/beer`.

Comment: OK, were getting closer. But this redirects me to http://www.domain.net/beer?p=beer

Comment: This is working, awesome! Thanks. Do you know if it's also possible to just show our www.domain.net/beer in the browser and get the page which would be opened by http://www.domain.net/index.php?p=beer. Because now, i get a 404.

Comment: @user2133694 Then you need a rewrite for both directions. Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15165778/1741542, it's almost the same.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:?

```
^([^/\.]+)\/?$
```

Otherwise I would try the .htacces without the other stuff.

Just:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Comment: this is the opposite of what was asked.