# Question mark in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make search results url look like Google.

> site.com/search?q=blabla

Tried this

```
RewriteRule ^search\?q=(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

I used `\` just before `?` but it still doesn't work, the question mark makes the problem. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond` to capture query strings. See [here](http://zenverse.net/capture-query-string-get-data-in-htaccess-rewrite/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212981/query-string-rewriting-using-htaccess).

Comment: But in this case, you can just leave the query string alone and rewrite `search/` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this simple rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Query string `?q=foobar` will be automatically carried over to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, this works for me to replace:

`example.com/search.php?q=hello`

With:

`example.com/search/hello/`

Code is:

```
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^search/?q=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /$1.php?q=$2`
```

Comment: The OP wants the URL to be `site.com/search?q=blabla`.

Comment: Edited, try the above.

Comment: I don't think you can capture query strings like that. [See here](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/).