# Htaccess Rewrite single query string

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with a rather old siye. I have some generic URL's with a query string, that i want to 301 redirect, but I don't want to blanket re-direct the urls. I want to choose where each query string is being redirected as there are  alot of different categories within the site. For example:

I want to change:

```
index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=199
```

to:

```
/garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html
```

But ill want to change another catid to another URL of my choosing, completely different structure. The problem I'm having is with the code i've got, if I don't have a ? at the end of the destination url, it works, but appends the query string to the end, if I put it on the end, it doesn't redirect at all.

Code I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_a=viewCat&catId=199 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html? [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The rest of my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^conservatory/(.*)$ /conservatory-furniture/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dining-room/(.*)$ /dining-room-furniture/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^garden/(.*)$ /garden-furniture/patio-furniture/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
 RewriteRule cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$   index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule prod_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule info_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=viewDoc&docId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule tell_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=tellafriend&productId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule _saleItems(\.[a-z]+)?(\?.*)?$   index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=saleItems&%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The redirection should work regardless of overriding the query string or not. What happens *exactly*, when you append a question mark at the end of the substitution? And do you have other rules as well?

Comment: If I place the ? at the end, then the link just breaks when its redirecting. Says it cant display the page (so I'm assuming the query string is not getting sent, so theres no page to generate?)

I do have some other rules, they are just creating the friendly URLs which i am redirecting to.

Comment: I guess, together with the corresponding other rule, you have an endless loop. Maybe this other answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/15165778/1741542

Comment: Ive tried the rules listed in this with no help either - not sure whats causing it - as the redirect with the question mark at the end, does work, well it sends it to the right place. It just doesn't produce a working page - is this because of an endless loop?

Comment: As I said, the question mark shouldn't change anything. There must be some other rule or directive causing this. As long as you don't show the other rules, it's just guesswork.

Comment: Sorry - edited to include the whole file!

Comment: It could be that the rule `RewriteRule cat_(...) index.php?...` redirects `/garden-furniture/.../` **cat_** `...` back to `index.php`, causing an endless loop.

Comment: Hmm - thats what was in place originally, and is what creates the pretty URL's in the first place. I know its probably not good practice to redirect to a pretty url. The 301 redirects at the top are all redirecting correctly. Any suggestions - im a bit stumped!

Comment: Well, I'm still guessing. It *could* be. See my answer to rule that out and see, if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

If these are complete URLs, you could anchor the pattern at the start of the string

```
RewriteRule ^cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$   index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1 [NC]
```

this would prevent an URL, which has `cat_` inside being rewritten to `index.php?...`.

And since you don't use the trailing *optional* part, you could eliminate this too

```
RewriteRule ^cat_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1 [NC]
```

Another point is the `RewriteCond` with query string. If the query string is optional, you could remove the `RewriteCond` and modify the `RewriteRule`s to

```
RewriteRule ^cat_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

So, all these would become

```
RewriteRule ^cat_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prod_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^info_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=viewDoc&docId=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^tell_([0-9]+) index.php?_a=tellafriend&productId=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^_saleItems index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=saleItems [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. These changes just break the site completely. Everything becomes a 404 error.